# Adding items to SP Folder inside document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, splistitem

I have a folder inside a document library. Inside this folder I need to check the existence of a sub-folder and then, add a document and another folder to it programmatically.

Lets say, my document library has a folder as "TopFolder", then within that I need to check if sub-folder "Project One" exists. If it does not exists, first create it.

And then within "Project One" folder,

i)  Add a document &

ii) Create a new folder.

So basically what would be the best way around to add a folder within a folder in a SharePoint document library?

I could do a CAML query and get the "TopFolder" but then how to check the nested folders within that and create new ones ?

Comment: So, are you expecting the answer with C# or PowerShell example?

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I'm doing this in a Application page's code behind, So I am using C#

Comment: Have you seen my answer, was it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

For uploading a file into a nested folder you could consider the following approach:

- ensure the target folder exist using the method provided below
- upload a file using [SPFileCollection.Add method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414180(v=office.15).aspx)

### How to ensure a nested Folder exist using SharePoint SSOM

```
internal static class SPFolderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensure SPFolder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web"></param>
    /// <param name="listTitle"></param>
    /// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SPFolder EnsureFolder(this SPWeb web, string listTitle, string folderUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderUrl))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folderUrl");
        var list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
        return CreateFolderInternal(list, list.RootFolder, folderUrl);
    }


    private static SPFolder CreateFolderInternal(SPList list, SPFolder parentFolder, string folderUrl)
    {
        var folderNames = folderUrl.Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var folderName = folderNames[0];

        var curFolder =
            parentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault( f => System.String.Compare(f.Name, folderName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
        if (curFolder == null)
        {
            var folderItem = list.Items.Add(parentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                                            folderName);
            folderItem.SystemUpdate();
            curFolder = folderItem.Folder;
        }


        if (folderNames.Length > 1)
        {
            var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderNames, 1, folderNames.Length - 1);
            return CreateFolderInternal(list, curFolder, subFolderUrl);
        }
        return curFolder;
    }
}
```

Gist: [EnsureFolder.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/f604d84d99cd260466b8)

---

The following example demonstrates how to ensure the following folder structure exist under `Documents` library and upload a file into it:

```
Orders
     |
     A --
        |
        A1
```

Example: how to upload a file into a nested folder

```
var targetFolder = web.EnsureFolder("Documents", "Orders3/A/A1");
var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
var fileUrl = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
targetFolder.Files.Add(fileUrl, fileContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is used to create a folder under document lib with "CurrentMonth Year"
if folder does not exists it creates new folder else add items to the folder .

```
string currentDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString(Constants.monthDateYearFormat);
string[] splitter = currentDate.Split(' ');
string folderName = splitter[0].ToString() + " " + splitter[2].ToString();

//Check if the Folder is already available in the doc lib                
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><Value Type='Text'>" + folderName + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value></Eq></And></Where>";

//delete below line for performance
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"";
//Retrieve the items based on Query                
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);


//if (!folderExists)
if (items.Count == 0)
                                {
                                    //// create a folder under the path specified 

                                    folderItem = list.AddItem(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);

                                    //// set the folder name and update 
                                    folderItem[Constants.folderTitle] = folderName;
                                    folderItem.Update();
                                        SPListItem listItem = list.AddItem(folderItem.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.File, null);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        folderItem = items[0];
                                        SPListItem listItem = list.AddItem(folderItem.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.File, null);

                                }
```